# Django order_by clause

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am new to both django and python but I am beginning to get a grasp on things. I think.
I have this problem and I can not seem to find an answer to it. my problem is in django queryset order_by clause

```
pp=Loksabha.objects.filter(state_name='MAHARASHTRA',constituency_name='Kolhapur').order_by('lok_sabha')
```

pp result is

```
Fifteenth Lok Sabha(2009-14)
Eleventh Lok Sabha(1996-98)
Fourteenth Lok Sabha(2004-09)
Tenth Lok Sabha(1991-96)
Thirteenth Lok Sabha(1999-04)
Sixth Lok Sabha(1977-79)
Ninth Lok Sabha(1989-91)
Seventh Lok Sabha(1980-84)
Fifth Lok Sabha(1971-77)
Fourth Lok Sabha(1967-71)
Second Lok Sabha(1957-62)
Twelfth Lok Sabha(1998-99)
```

but i want to result like this formt

```
Fifteenth Lok Sabha(2009-14)
Fourteenth Lok Sabha(2004-09)
Thirteenth Lok Sabha(1999-04)
Twelfth Lok Sabha(1998-99)
Eleventh Lok Sabha(1996-98)
Tenth Lok Sabha(1991-96)
Ninth Lok Sabha(1989-91)
Sixth Lok Sabha(1977-79)
Fifth Lok Sabha(1971-77)
Fourth Lok Sabha(1967-71)
Second Lok Sabha(1957-62)
```

my model is:

```
class Loksabha(models.Model):
    lok_sabha = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    member_name =  models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    constituency_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    party_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

please give me proper solution.

Comment: Pramod , paste here Loksabha models .

Comment: My suggestion to you is to normalize your model . add field for start year and end year . then you can easily get details that you want .

Comment: @PriyankPatel but my table have fixed column

Comment: So you can't add this two fields ? `lok_sabha_start_year = models.IntegerField(null=True,Blank=True)` and `lok_sabha_end_year = models.IntegerField(null=True,Blank=True)` and then `syncdb` . Because you have few records , you can manually enter records from existing field `lok_sabha` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your queryset should be ordered by the attribute `lok_sabbah` in alphabetical order from the code you wrote here. Meanwhile, I don't know what you're using when 'printing' your model.

Could you copy/paste us your **str** method to be sure of the printed result?

Maybe, you just need an `order_by(pk)` if the names follow the order of their creation...